# Control Animation in BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine

is it possible to play, pause, and stop the animation with plane as image in blender? i need to use the button to control my animation in BGE. but i don't know how to make it. can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use "mouse over" and "mouse click" sensors with a and controller to detect click on planes and use it to play, pause or reset animation actuators.